# Open or search resources in external jars

Tags: eclipse, jar, resources, external

Is there a way to use "Open Resource" or Search -> File in eclipse to find resource files (eg *.js, *.css) in external jars?

Answer (score 0):

Add those external jars into the project, preferably in a different folder. And search - > file by entering the file name in the **Containing Text** field and * * in **File Name Patterns**